# Signs and Wonders

Tags: word, knowledge, crosswords

The answer is a word (9)
Prefer no partial answers please

[image: crossword]

**ACROSS**
**1**  Sign
**3**  Location of wonder featured in 12A and 27A
**5**  Sign
**8**  Location of modern wonder featuring 17D
**9**  Location of modern wonder built by the Mayans
**12**  Structure dedicated to 27A
**15**  Sign
**16**  Location of modern wonder built by the Inca
**17**  Black bird sometimes signifying death or an ill omen
**18**  Location of an ancient wonder
**21**  Sign
**22**  Father of man who performed the wonder of halting the sun in the sky
**23**  Sign on a die?
**24**  Name for miraculous movement out of Egypt
**25**  Sign
**26**  Norse god associated with lightning and thunder
**27**  Deity honored by an ancient wonder
**28**  Relating to the country housing 39A
**29**  Public marketplace near 39A?
**32**  Destination for those involved with 24A
**33**  Mythical king who slew a deer sacred to 27A
**35**  Wondrous national park in Alberta
**37**  Modern wonder
**38**  Sign
**39**  Ancient wonder

**DOWN**
**2**  Modern wonder, with 36D
**4**  Glass footwear that's a sign of magic
**6**  "Eternal City" housing a modern wonder
**7**  Sign
**8**  Location of 18D
**10**  Ancient wonder
**11**  Ancient wonder
**13**  Structure found at 18A
**14**  Structure found at 25D
**17**  Subject of modern wonder
**18**  Ancient wonder
**19**  Sign
**20**  Sign
**23**  Sign
**25**  Location of an ancient wonder
**30**  Sign
**31**  Modern wonder
**34**  Sign
**36**  Modern wonder, with 2D

[image: boxes]

Comment: looks cool. wish i could dig into it, but busy at work

Comment: Let me guess 7 old and new wonders of the world and 12 signs of the zodiac

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

In the grid there are

> 9 lone black squares surrounded by white squares. Using the key at the bottom and coloring the appropriate squares yellow gives the word **PROMINENT**!